# calculate mean length of a line using C

Tags: c, string, character

I have a text file which I have filled a number lines from different texts, having different line length. 
What I want to do is calculate the average number characters per line which matters to me in my job. I wrote the following code in C to achieve this. However I cannot run the program once it is compiled.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 10000000

int main()
{
    char c;
    int i;
    int line_length;
    int j;
    int char_count;
    char char_a[LENGTH];
    int line_a[LENGTH];
    int line_count;
    long sum;
    float avg_char_count;
    FILE *fp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr,"cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    /*read into file*/
    i=0;
    sum=0;
    while(char_a[i++]=fgetc(fp))
            sum++;

    printf("chars count: %d \n",sum);

    /*process array*/
    char_count=i;
    j=0;    
    line_count=0;
    while(j++<char_count){
        if(char_a[j]=='\n'){
            sum--;
            line_count++;
        }   
    }

    /* calculate the average*/
    avg_char_count=sum/(float)line_count;
    printf("\naverage # of chars in a line is: %f\n ",avg_char_count);
    return  EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

By the way I am using Borland C++ command-line tool BCC32, running on Windows 7 SP1.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Does it compile ? Does it fail when running ? Does it run but returns a wrong output ? Please give more info on your actual problem.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to how your program fails. What output do you get? Any exceptions?

Comment: It fails in running. Windows opens up a popup saying "avg.exe has stopped working". When I run it in command line, I see no output.

Comment: More Info <br/> Problem signature:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: avg.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 00000000
  Fault Module Name: avg.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000011ac
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1065
  Additional Information 1: 2d0f
  Additional Information 2: 2d0f4d9134f55833e7fdd1b383e9e851
  Additional Information 3: 4445
  Additional Information 4: 44455f5d9a03194691b8551759ddcdec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring char_a and line_a as pointers to char and int as:

```
char *char_a;
int *line_a;
```

And then allocate memory dynamically using malloc.

```
char_a=(char*)malloc(10000000*sizeof(char));
line_a=(int*)malloc(10000000*sizeof(int));
```

Secondly, your while loop should end when you reach end of file, i.e. EOF.

```
while(char_a[i]=fgetc(fp)){
            if(char_a[i++]==EOF)
                break;

                sum++;
     }
```

And, you should initialize the line_count to 1 instead of 0, because when there is no '\n' in the text file, there can still be one line. If there is one '\n' in the text file, it means there are two lines (say, you are in line 1, and then you hit enter, which is '\n', and then you get to the new line, so for one '\n', there are 2 lines).

```
    /*process array*/
    char_count=sum;
    j=0;
    line_count=1;
    while(j++<char_count){
        if(char_a[j]=='\n'){
            sum--;
            line_count++;
        }
    }
```

NOTE-Currently your char_count include newlines ('\n') when it is printed. Print the statement in the end, because in the end of your program, you have already excluded the newlines by decrementing the sum in the if statement of the second while loop.

Comment: You should never declare any variable as global. If you need to move something to file scope, you should declare it as static. Also in this case it is not helpful, because in every mainstream OS, such huge amounts of memory should always be allocated on the heap on never anywhere else.

Comment: @user3340994 Doesn't `while(char_a[i]=fgetc(fp)){` automatically check for EOF?

Comment: while() and if() etc take 0 as false. but fgetc(fp) returns the character read, and when the file ends, it will return EOF. but EOF is not 0. EOF is generally -1 (system dependent actually). so, you cant use it to break your while() loop. that's why your while() loop never ends and program does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is that you allocate 20 Mb of variables on the stack.

I would change the program so that it reads the file on line at a time (or even one character at a time).
That way you only need to allocate space for one line and not for the entire file.